# Symfony 5 - How to make an admin backend

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I need to create an admin backend where I will be able to access all my CRUD routes.

For now here's the controllers I have :

- `MainController` (For all my public routes)
- `AdminController`
- `WordController` (/word CRUD routes)
- `TypeController` (/type CRUD routes)

For my backend I need somes routes like :

- `/admin/` (this will be something like a dashboard)
- `/admin/word/`
- `/admin/word/new`
- `/admin/type/new`

How can I verify if the user is logged in for every route that begin with `/admin` ? What is the best approach for this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

In your `security.yaml` file add:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```